Why does my cloth object breaks into many parts after trying to animate?
I imported a dress i made in CLO3D to Blender to animate it. I applied cloth physics so i could use wind but when i use wind my dress breaks into many parts.



Hello, maybe some edges are ripped, what does it give if you merge by distance?

How can i merge by distance? (im a blender begginer).

Select all in Edit mode and press M > Merge by Distance, but maybe share your file so that we can test it? https://blend-exchange.com/

Added, i did try but the mesh still gets stretched, any way i can add weight paint to choose how much i want each part to move?

It seems your model is in fact a few separate objects. Did you try to combine them using Ctrl+J and then apply the cloth sim?

The rest of the objects are the mannequin and the support of it, the dress is all together. I only apllied cloth to the dress.

Your dress has a very bad topology, I think it doesn't help for the cloth simulation, you'd better retopologize with a clean topology with quads

Converted it to quads, even tho it doesnt disconnect it still deforms, is there any solution for this or should i just try to animate it in clo3d and then export the animation to blender?

you say that it still deforms, how do you want it to deform exactly? The cloth simulation will deform your object of course

I mean deform because it doesnt just move like its getting hit by the wind, it stretches. I only want it to move the skirt and not stretch.

Could you please share the new (retopologized) version?

Forgot to update, i managed to do the animation but i didnt do it on Blender. I did the animation in Clo3D then i exported and imported to Blender and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your help, i can still share the file if you wanna discover it yourself, just let me know if u still want it.

As you want, I'm just a bit surprised that your cloth stretches so I could take a look at the settings

You can download the one already linked, i only converted the triangles to quads and thats when it stopped separating and started stretching.

What method did you use to convert tris to quads?

Selected all in edit mode then right click "Trips to Quads".
